# How to query the pivot table

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4

I need to query the pivot table project_user to get the column where done = 1, and where the project id that exist in project_user. ? How to use this in Eloquent ? .

Thank you in advance.

```
projects
   -id
   -user_id

users 
    -id

project_users
   -user_id
   -project_id
   -done



class Projec extends Model{

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('done');
    }

}




 class User extends Model{
        public function projects(){
          return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class)->withPivot('done');
        }
 }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? The users of a project that are done? The projects of a user that are done?

Comment: projec of user that are done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User::find($id)->projects()->wherePivot('done', 1)->get();
```